# flexbox vertical align child top, center another

Tags: css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I've got the following markup:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  
  margin: -16px;
  background: #ddd;
}

.row .col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  
  flex: 1;
  
  margin: 16px;
  background: #fff;
}

.header, .content, .footer {
  padding: 16px;
  
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="header">Header #1</div>
        <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum<br />Dolor<br />Sit Amet</div>
        <div class="footer">Footer</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
        <div class="header">Header #2</div>
        <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum<br />Dolor</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunatly the second header isn't align vertically to the top. Is there a way to archive this with flexbox? I need the ".header" to be aligned the the top and the ".content" to be centered within the rest of the box.

Greetings!

Comment: This might be helpful: [Methods for Aligning Flex Items](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not really, not without another wrapper which is a flex-container.

As flexbox is, to a certain extent based on manipulting margins, there is no method (AFAIK, *although I'd be interested to find out if there is*) to `justify-content: center` and then `align-self` a child element to somewhere else other than center.

I'd go with something like this: Add a wrapper to the "content" div, give it `flex:1` to fill the remaining space below the header, then make that wrapper `display:flex` with `justify-content:center`.

This seems to be the most logical method

```css
.col {
  height: 150px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.header {
  background: lightblue;
}
.content {
  background: orange;
}
.flexy {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  background: plum;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <div class="header">Header #2</div>
  <div class="flexy">
    <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum
      <br />Dolor</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/zvQPNJ)

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for your answer! I hoped I could skip another wrapper :D

Answer (score 2):

Flexbox opens up all sorts of opportunities with `margin: auto;` this is one of them. Setting `margin` to `auto` along the flex axis (vertical in this case) will absorb any extra space before dividing it up between the flex items. Finally it's possible to vertically center stuff without creating a div soup.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  
  margin: -16px;
  background: #ddd;
}

.row .col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  flex: 1;
  
  margin: 16px;
  background: #fff;
}

.header, .content, .footer {
  padding: 16px;
  
  background: red;
}

.content {
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="header">Header #1</div>
        <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum<br />Dolor<br />Sit Amet</div>
        <div class="footer">Footer</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
        <div class="header">Header #2</div>
        <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum<br />Dolor</div>
    </div>
</div>
```